# Проблемы c получением всего набора тегов при парсинге сайта

Tags: html, python-3.x, парсер

В учебных целях пытаюсь парсить сайт автообъявлений https://ab.onliner.by, 
цель парсинга получить ссылки на авто, ссылка выглядит как "https://ab.onliner.by/car/ID". При анализе сайта через браузер четко видно, что вожделенный ID машины обитает внутри тега:

```
<a href="/car/4164123"><img width="80" height="80" src="https://content.onliner.by/automarket/2218487/80x80/496c37de7ec4ec3eabf6eb66e6c9bb24.jpeg"></a>
```

Проблема в том, что в возвращаемом HTML коде этого тега нет

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text

print(get_html('https://ab.onliner.by'))
```

Собственно возникает вопросы что упускаю/не так делаю?

Comment: Смо́трите сгенерированный DOM в браузере вместо того, чтобы смотреть реальный исходный код страницы. Нажмите ПКМ → «Просмотр кода страницы» (или «Исходный код страницы») в том же браузере, и увидите, что никаких ссылок там и в самом деле нет, а они генерируются на лету джаваскриптом

Comment: А как из Python заставить сгенерировать  эту страницу?

Comment: @Александр Используйте пакет Selenium вместе с Chrome или Firefox. Есть и ряд headless браузеров, чтобы это делать полностью в фоне, но до них я пока не добрался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для загрузки страницы со скриптами используйте пакет Selenium вместе с Chrome или Firefox.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
chrome_driver = 'C:/Tools/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe' 
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver, options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://ab.onliner.by')

# Таймаут, чтобы JS успели отработать.
# Использование time.sleep - это грубый и не очень надёжный подход
# Лучше почитать и использовать Expected Conditions из того же Selenium
# from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
# from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
time.sleep(5) 

print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Да так работает, спасибо!

Comment: В фоновом режиме chrome_options.add_argument('headless')

Comment: И это chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x935')

Comment: Мне интересно а без установленного браузера будет работать?

Comment: @Александр, без установленного браузера - не будет